# Laravel | How to group store items in database with form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using a database table with default tasks defined, and I'm using a 'foreach()' in my form to cycle through them. Every task has a checkbox and if it's unchecked, the data will not go into the database. When there is only 1 task definied for that specific project, it's not a problem. But when there are multiple tasks defined, it only picks the last task and stores it into the database. I need to store them all, and not just that 1 last task.

**I'm using jQuery to disable the fields when the checkbox is unchecked**

This is my form code:

```
     <form id="task-form"
        class="uk-form-stacked"
        method="post"
        action="{{ route('project.storeTasks', ['project' => $project->id]) }}">

        <table class="uk-table uk-table-middle">
            <tr>
                <th>Selecteer</th>
                <th>Omschrijving</th>
                <th>Toelichting</th>
                <th>Uitvoering door</th>
                <th>Budget</th>
                <th>Deadline</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach($defaulttasks as $task)

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox"
                                class="uk-checkbox selected"
                                name="tasks[{{ $task->id }}][checkbox]"
                                value="{{ $task->id }}"
                                checked>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="uk-margin">
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <input type="text"
                                    class="input uk-input uk-width-1-1"
                                    name="tasks[{{ $task->id }}][title]"
                                    value="{{ old('title', isset($task->title)
                                                ? $task->title
                                                : null) }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="uk-margin">
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <textarea class="input uk-textarea uk-width-1-1"
                                        name="tasks[{{ $task->id }}][description]"
                                        rows="1"
                                        value="">{{ old('description', isset($task->description)
                                                    ? $task->description
                                                    : null) }}</textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="uk-margin">
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <select class="input uk-select uk-width-1-1" name="tasks[{{ $task->id }}][teammember]">
                                    {{-- @foreach($project->team as $teammember)
                                        <!-- <option value="{{ $teammember->id }}">{{ $teammember->name }}</option> -->
                                    @endforeach --}}
                                </select>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="uk-margin">
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <input type="number"
                                    class="input uk-input"
                                    name="tasks[{{ $task->id }}][budget]"
                                    step="any"
                                    value="{{ old('budget', isset($task->budget)
                                                ? $task->budget
                                                : null) }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="uk-margin">
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <input type="text"
                                    class="input uk-input"
                                    name="tasks[{{ $task->id }}][deadline]"
                                    value="{{ old('deadline', isset($task->deadline)
                                                ? $task->deadline
                                                : null) }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>               

                    <input class="input" type="hidden" name="project_id" value="{{ $project->id }}">
                </tr>

            @endforeach

        {{ csrf_field() }}
        </table>                                    
    </form>
```

This is my function to store items into the database:

```
public function quickAddTask(Projects $cached_projects, $project, Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    if(!empty($input['tasks']) && is_array($input['tasks']))
    {
        foreach($input['tasks'] as $id => $task)
        {
            // Create new task entry.
            $new_task = new Task([
                'project_id' => (integer) $input['project_id'],
                'title' => $task['title'],
                'description' => $task['description'],
                'status' => (integer) 1,
                'user_id' => (integer) 17,
                'budget' => $task['budget'],
                'deadline' => Carbon::parse($task['deadline'])->toDateString()
            ]);

            // Find the project and attach the new task to the project.
            $project = $cached_projects->find($project);
            $project->tasks()->save($new_task);

            // Flush cache.
            Cache::tags('tasks')->flush();

            // Set message and reload the tasks view.
            setMessage('De taken zijn met succes toegevoegd aan het project.', 'success');
            return redirect()->route('project.tasks', ['project' => $project->id]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Find the project.
        $project = $cached_projects->find($project);

        // Set message and reload the notes view.
        setMessage('Er zijn geen taken aan het project toegevoegd.', 'danger');
        return redirect()->route('project.tasks', ['project' => $project->id]);
    }
}
```

**If you guys need more information tell me!**

Thanks.

**EDIT:** With the changes I made with help from FrankerZ, it only stores the first selected task and not all selected tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your input elements into an array. If you output `<input name="test" />` multiple times on a webpage, only the last input is submitted when the request is sent to the server. PHP automatically supports converting to arrays when you use bracket notation (ie. `task[$id]`). Convert your fields:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox"
                class="uk-checkbox selected"
                name="tasks[{{ $task->id }}][checkbox]"
                value="{{ $task->id }}"
                checked>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                <input type="text"
                    class="input uk-input uk-width-1-1"
                    name="tasks[{{ $task->id }}][title]"
                    value="{{ old('title', isset($task->title)
                                ? $task->title
                                : null) }}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                <textarea class="input uk-textarea uk-width-1-1"
                        name="tasks[{{ $task->id }}][description]"
                        rows="1"
                        value="">{{ old('description', isset($task->description)
                                    ? $task->description
                                    : null) }}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>

    <td>
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                <input type="number"
                    class="input uk-input"
                    name="tasks[{{ $task->id }}][budget]"
                    step="any"
                    value="{{ old('budget', isset($task->budget)
                                ? $task->budget
                                : null) }}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                <input type="text"
                    class="input uk-input"
                    name="tasks[{{ $task->id }}]deadline"
                    value="{{ old('deadline', isset($task->deadline)
                                ? $task->deadline
                                : null) }}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>               

    <input class="input" type="hidden" name="project_id" value="{{ $project->id }}">
</tr>
```

Then you can loop through in laravel like:

```
$input = $request->all();
if(!empty($input['tasks']) && is_array($input['tasks']))
{
    foreach ($input['tasks'] as $id => $task) {
        // Create new task entry.
        $new_task = new Task([
            'project_id' => (integer) $input['project_id'],
            'title' => $task['title'],
            'description' => $task['description'],
            'status' => (integer) 1,
            'user_id' => (integer) 17,
            'budget' => $task['budget'],
            'deadline' => Carbon::parse($task['deadline'])->toDateString()
        ]);

        // Find the project and attach the new task to the project.
        $project = $cached_projects->find($project);
        $project->tasks()->save($new_task);

    }
    // Flush cache.
    Cache::tags('tasks')->flush();

    // Set message and reload the tasks view.
    setMessage('De taak is met succes toegevoegd aan het project.', 'success');
    return redirect()->route('project.tasks', ['project' => $project->id]);
}
else
{
    // Find the project.
    $project = $cached_projects->find($project);

    setMessage('Er zijn geen taken aan het project toegevoegd.', 'danger');
    return redirect()->route('project.tasks', ['project' => $project->id]);
}
```

Comment: It does work, but not completely. I changed the names of the input fields like you mentioned. But when I do '`dd($request->checkbox)`' it only gives me the id's of the tasks, and not all the other inputs: `array:3 [▼
  14 => "14"
  15 => "15"
  16 => "16"
]`. So what you did doesn't work. I get this error: **Trying to get property 'title' of non-object**

Comment: @iiRobin I did update it before the grace period. Are you using my updated code?

Comment: I updated my code like you did. It doesn't give me an error anymore, but instead of storing multiple tasks, it now stores only the first one.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($new_task)` and make sure that you're seeing each new task being created. I'd then investigate `$project->tasks()->save()` and see how it supports multiple additions (Not a laravel expert, sorry)

Comment: When i do `var_dump($new_task)` it indeed only shows me the first task that is selected with the checkbox, and not all the tasks that are selected,

Comment: You added that right before the `$project->tasks()->save()` line?

Comment: Are the `$task->id` unique on the front end? Can you take a look at what's being sent to the server (The network tab), and share a screenshot of the actual request being sent to the server?

Comment: Yes I added it before `$project->tasks()->save()`. And the `$task->id`'s are all unique. What do you want me to screenshot? The var_dump outcome?

Comment: I don't see any task information at all. You sure you have the right POST request? Check the box that says preserve log, clear the console, and then submit the form again. Find the POST request, and post THAT log.

Comment: Under the "Request Headers" there is something called "Form Data". There is all the data that went through with the form. The data of every checkbox that is checked is right there. https://imgur.com/a/XvPyu2A

Comment: Alright, I'm about at the end of where I can help effectively without actually sitting down at your computer or debugging remotely. `var_dump($input)`. Is it an array with the list of tasks you want? If so: Alright, loop through that, and investigate how to add or update each task (I'm assuming at this point that the tasks are already made, and you're updating them). If it's only saving the first or last, then the loop is screwed up somewhere, or you're not providing some ID, or it's being overwritten on the DB level. Debug the query on the database.

Comment: If you're still stuck and having issues, update your original post with the information from these comments (and anything else you may have found out), and see if someone can help further.

Comment: The `var_dump($input)` is giving me all the data I want.

Comment: Thanks for your help @FrankerZ

Comment: @iiRobin What was your solution?

Comment: I didn't place `$project = $cached_projects->find($project);` and `$project->tasks()->save($new_task);` inside the 'foreach()'. That's what crewed up.

Comment: Lol, that would do it